# Splash screen when initializing, connecting and logging in

Tags: android

I am very new to Android and am a beginner programmer. I am making a prototype of an app that displays a slash screen, initializes, connects to a server (haven't worked on this yet), determines if login information is needed (if so goes to the `LoginActivity`), then logs in.

Right now this is a prototype so initialize, connect and login function just return true.

The trouble I am having is the the splash screen examples I have found on the web only have a wait in the thread. Also, in debug, when  `setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen)` is called, it doesn't immediately load the screen.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
public class LoadingScreenActivity extends Activity {
private Thread mLoadingScreenThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final LoadingScreenActivity loading_screen = this;  


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);        

    mLoadingScreenThread =  new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            boolean loggedIn = false;

            synchronized(this)
            {
                while(loggedIn == false)
                {
                    if (initialize()) //Initialize
                    {
                        if (connectToServer()) //Connect to Server                              
                        {
                            //Check to see if we need login information or registration
                            if (needLogin())
                            {
                                //Load LoginActivity and have user Login
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setClass(loading_screen, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }                               
                            //Login to server
                            if (login())
                            {
                                loggedIn = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //We are initialized, connected and logged in
            finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(loading_screen, UserMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            stop();                    
        }
    };

    mLoadingScreenThread.start();        
}

//Determine if we need the user to provide login information
private boolean needLogin() 
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoadingScreenActivity.this, "Checking for Login Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    waitForMilliseconds(5000);
    return true;
}

//Initialize Application
private boolean initialize() 
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoadingScreenActivity.this, "Inializing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    waitForMilliseconds(5000);
    return true;
}

//Connect Application to Server
private boolean connectToServer()   
{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoadingScreenActivity.this, "Connecting to Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    waitForMilliseconds(5000);
    return true;
}

private boolean login() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(LoadingScreenActivity.this, "Logging In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
    waitForMilliseconds(5000);
    return true;
}

private void waitForMilliseconds(int milliseconds)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    try {
        timer.wait(milliseconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but it seems as if you've mixed two concepts.

A splash screen is simply an image/animation on a timer (or while something is loading).
Having a login-functionality doesn't have any obvious connection to the concept of a splash screen as far as I can tell. You simply want a normal activity which takes some input (login info) and then processes it (checks a database for example).

And when you say that it doesn't load the image immediately, do you mean that it lags somehow, or simply stays black for a while. You might need a loading(splash)screen separate from the login activity to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
Let me see if I can clarify. 
I want to have the splash screen up while the applications checks to see:
1. If the username and password is already saved, then can auto login)
2. If the username and password is not already saved, opens the LoginActivity (which has a link to the Register Activity).
3. After the user provides the username and password, I would like it to go back to the splash screen so it can initialize, connect and login.
4. After login occurs I want the splash screen to end and go to the UserMainActivity.

Does that help? (im still figuring it out)

Leon